# AWS ECS: ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

**Background**

Testing VPC:

- 2 private subnets with NACLS that allow all inbound from IPs within the VPC and all outbound traffic. The subnets have a route table configured to a NAT gateway within a public subnet.
- 2 public subnets that allow all inbound/outbound traffic. One of the subnets contains the NAT gateway and both subnets have a route table pointing to the Internet Gateway.

**Problem**

When running an ECS Fargate task (platform: `1.4`) within one of the private subnets, the following error arises:

```
ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve ecr registry auth: service call has been retried 3 time(s): RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post https://api.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp <IP>:443: i/o timeout
```

The ECS task contains one container that uses a private ECR image hosted within the same AWS account. The security group associated with the task allows all inbound traffic from IPs within the VPC and allows all outbound traffic.

ECS task execution role contains the following policies:

```
"arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy",
"arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
```

Attempts:

- When the private subnets NACL's inbound access was changed to allow all types of traffic, the ECS task was strangely able to pull the ECR image.
- Created the VPC endpoints mentioned in this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) with the correct security groups but got the same error.
- I'm tempted to try following this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html) although it specifically says:

```
If your task definition references an image that's stored in Amazon ECR, this topic doesn't apply.
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are pulling an image from ECR?

If you are launching via ecs-cli, add this to the ecs-params.yml
(read about that file here: https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli)

Firstly: **auto-assign public IP addresses** ->

```
run_params:
  network_configuration:
    awsvpc_configuration:
      subnets:
        - "subnet-06786b976xx"
        - "subnet-0b9dxxxxxxx"
      security_groups:
        - "sg-08157xxxxxxxxx4"
      assign_public_ip: "ENABLED"
```

Secondly make sure that the **security groups you use for your VPC allow 80/443 traffic**

Thirdly make sure in AWS IMA that the execution role (ecsTaskExecutionRole) has policies including:

- AWSAppRunnerServicePolicyForECRAccess

Comment: This solved the issue for me, thank you! Including full error message for searchability:  "Resourceinitializationerror: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve ecr registry auth: service call has been retried 3 time(s): RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post "https://api.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp ... i/o timeout"